# Add Guice DI on an exisitng spring DI application

Tags: java, spring, guice

I am trying to install guice dependencies in a spring package. However, I am getting "No qualifying bean of type 'class from where guice injection is done' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate " error . I am not sure why there is a need to create a bean for guice injection. Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: You need to add more details/code/stack traces. I'd suggest stick with one DI framework but I don't know what you're attempting to do as there's not enough detail in the question

Comment: I was just trying to add guice DI on an existing appilcation which is using spring DI. I believe guice is preferred these days.

Comment: just did a search for guice / spring on a job listing website: 772 jobs advertised that use "spring" (and therefore spring DI), 2 jobs with Guice listed. Thats a clear indication of which is more prevalent.

Comment: That's just the way spring works, there are examples here on how to go both ways. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-guice  If you don't want to write an `@Bean` for each, you can use the Guice SPI to review bindings to perform it automatically.